# Using the sum of the columns, to create a new varible

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have data set, that has States, Corn, and Cotton. I want to create a new variable, Corn_Pct in SAS (% of state corn output relative to the country's output of corn). The same for Cotton_pct.
sample of data: (numbers are not real)

```
    State Corn Cotton
    TX    135  500
    AK    120  350
    ...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What output do you expect for the sample data you have posted? What did you try? How was the result different than what you wanted?

Comment: I should get two new columns. At first I tried [Corn_pct = (corn /sum(of corn))*100;], but this just gave me 100. I didn't realized that one there is only one variable in [sum], that I'll just get that number back. I know there is a way to do this, I just can't remember it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a simple `Proc SQL`. Let the dataset be "Test",

```
Proc sql ;
create table test_percent as 
select *,
Corn/sum(corn) as Corn_Pct format=percent7.1,
Cotton/sum(Cotton) as Cotton_Pct format=percent7.1
from test
;
quit;
```

If you have many columns, you can use `Arrays` and `do loops` to automatically generate percentages everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I have calculated the total of a column in `Inner Query` and then used that total for the calculation in outer query using `Cross Join`

Hey Try this:-

```
 /*My Dataset */
    Data Test;
    input     State $  Corn  Cotton ;
    cards;
    TK 135 500
    AK 120 350
    CK 100 250
    FG 200 300
    run;

    /*Code*/

    Proc sql;
    create table test_percent as 
    Select a.*, (corn * 100/sm_corn) as Corn_pct, (Cotton * 100/sm_cotton) as Cotton_pct
    from test a
    cross join
    (
    select sum(corn) as sm_corn ,
    sum(Cotton) as sm_cotton
    from test
    ) b ;
    quit;

        /*My Output*/
 State Corn Cotton    Corn_pct     Cotton_pct
     TK 135  500      24.32432432   35.71428571
     AK 120  350      21.62162162   25
     CK 100  250      18.01801802   17.85714286
     FG 200  300      36.03603604   21.42857143
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an alternative using `proc means` and `data step`:

```
proc means data=test sum noprint;
    output out=test2(keep=corn cotton) sum=corn cotton;
quit;

data test_percent (drop=corn_sum cotton_sum);
    set test2(rename=(corn=corn_sum cotton=cotton_sum) in=in1) test(in=in2);
    if (in1=1) then do;
        call symput('corn_sum',corn_sum);
        call symput('cotton_sum',cotton_sum);
    end;
    else do;
        Corn_pct = corn/symget('corn_sum');
        Cotton_pct = cotton/symget('cotton_sum');
    output;
    end;
run;
```